# Suddenly getting Error in server build process (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

I cannot remember changing anything on my conputer but since around 18:40 CET I have not been able anymore to send any build to CN1. Here is the error it shows :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1022)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1020)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1019)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1281)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1280)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.uploadToS3(BuildProcess.java:305)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:366)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:432)
at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

/home/path/to/myProject/build.xml:338: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 15 seconds)
```

I did not change the way I am sending the build either, what should I do ?

Any help appreciated,

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is related to the Amazon outage people are experiencing world wide. Try again after the issues are figured out at Amazon. I am unable to download my previous builds as well.

You could follow the status here:

> https://status.aws.amazon.com/
>
> https://twitter.com/awscloud